# Android: How to get a view's height

Tags: android, layoutparams

For example, this is `mButton`:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/mbtn"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="mButton" />
```

This is how I tried to get the height:

```
int height = mButton.getLayoutParams.height;
```

But when I logged it, it says the height is -2. I think this might be the int value of "wrap_content". So how can I get the actual height? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the width or height of a view in activty
you can get in this method..

```
yourview.getHeight();
```

returns zero(0) after initialization of the button because after adding it to the window only it has a width..in the below method you can height and width of a view..

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    yourview.getHeight();
    yourview.getWidth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**After layout has happened** call [View.getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29):

> `public final int getHeight()`
>
> Return the height of your view.
>
> **Returns**
>   The height of your view, in pixels.

As you guessed, `layoutParams.height` is just the value of `wrap_content` in your case, which is -2.  You could set `layoutParams.height` to a desired height, but even then it's not necessarily the height that the view will actually end up with after all layout is done.

Answer (score 0):

override the method onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus);

inside write your code,

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
mbtn.getHeight();
mbtn.getWidth();
}
```

it will give the correct result of the view dimensions.